# Enforce continuous math environment when concatenating multiple math environments

Tags: math-mode, acronyms

I have a non-standard setup for my symbols. Instead of defining them explicitly in every equation, e.g.:

```
\begin{equation}
a_i={\bf b}^{(est)}_i \cdot {\bf c}^{(obs)}_i
\end{equation}
```

I define acronyms (with the acronym package):

```
\acro{a}[$a$]{scalar quantity a}
\acro{b}[${\bf b}$]{vector quantity b}
\acro{c}[${\bf c}$]{vector quantity c}
\acro{epoch.i}[$_i$]{epoch $i$}
\acro{dot}[$\cdot$]{dot product}
\acro{est}[$^{(est}}$]{estimated}
\acro{obs}[$^{(obs}}$]{observed}
```

... and use the short form in the equations:

```
\begin{equation}
\acs{a}\acs{epoch.i}=\acs{b}\acs{est}\acs{epoch.i}\acs{dot}\acs{c}\acs{obs}\acs{epoch.i}
\end{equation}
```

The motivation to do things in this way is do that I can relate a symbol to its meaning textually, such as:

> The \acl{obs} \acl{b} is represented by \acs{b}\acs{obs}.

... and I get a consistent list of symbols for free.

The problem is when there are superscript mixed with subscripts, e.g.:

```
{\bf b}^{(est)}_i;
```

... what I effectively get is:

```
${\bf b}$$^{(est)}$$_i$
```

... which means that there is a concatenation of math environments instead of a continuous one, resulting that the subscript appears after the superscript and not under it, as in the usual way.

Any suggestions to fix this without destroying my nice acronym setup?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyon

Comment: This must surely generate errors in any display math environment not just in superscripts, also it will generate poorer spacing than would otherwise be the case your `_i` for example, will always superscript a null atom and so will not take account of the size of the thing being subscripted or of any font specified kerning: compare `$P_i$` with `$P{}_i$`

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the heads up. I forgot about the MWE. My bad. I focused on explaining the issue but that's no substitute, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how much can go wrong with this; for instance it doesn't work with `hyperref`, but is a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\protected\def\EM#1{\relax\ifmmode#1\else$#1$\fi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\acsm[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{fn@#1}
    {\underline{#1}}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo\csname fn@#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{a}[\EM{a}]{scalar quantity a}
  \acro{b}[\EM{\mathbf{b}}]{vector quantity b}
  \acro{c}[\EM{\mathbf{c}}]{vector quantity c}
  \acro{epoch.i}[\EM{_i}]{epoch $i$}
  \acro{dot}[\EM{\cdot}]{dot product}
  \acro{est}[\EM{^{(est)}}]{estimated}
  \acro{obs}[\EM{^{(obs)}}]{observed}
  \acro{sum}[\EM{\sum}]{sum}
\end{acronym}

\begin{equation}
\acsm{a}\acsm{epoch.i}=\acsm{b}\acsm{est}\acsm{epoch.i}\acsm{dot}\acsm{c}\acsm{obs}\acsm{epoch.i}
\end{equation}

\[\acsm{b}\acsm{est}\acsm{epoch.i}\acsm{sum}_{1\le k\le n}a_k\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a strange way to write TeX to me:) Nonetheless, I think that you can do what you want if you just use `\ensuremath` instead of explicitly entering math-mode with `$...$` inside your acronyms:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{a}[\ensuremath{a}]{scalar quantity a}
  \acro{b}[\ensuremath{{\mathbf b}}]{vector quantity b}
  \acro{c}[\ensuremath{{\mathbf c}}]{vector quantity c}
  \acro{epoch.i}[\ensuremath{{}_i}]{epoch $i$}
  \acro{dot}[\ensuremath{\cdot}]{dot product}
  \acro{est}[\ensuremath{{}^{(est)}}]{estimated}
  \acro{obs}[\ensuremath{{}^{(obs)}}]{observed}
\end{acronym}

\begin{equation}
\acs{a}\acs{epoch.i}=\acs{b}\acs{est}\acs{epoch.i}\acs{dot}\acs{c}\acs{obs}\acs{epoch.i}
\end{equation}

$\acs{b}\acs{est}\acs{epoch.i}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: I know you copied from the OP, but `\bf b` should be `\mathbf{b}` and `(est)` should be `\mathrm(est)` and same for `obs`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are correct. I posted the question quickly and overlooked that. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you. Your example is very useful because of things like `\ensuremath{{}^{(est}}`.

Comment: I'm afraid I was too quick to identify this as the correct answer. In fact, the sub/superscript appear one after the other, not flushed to the left next to the main symbol. Compare: `$\ensuremath{{\mathbf b}}\ensuremath{{}^{(est)}}\ensuremath{{}_i}$` (not good) with `$\ensuremath{{\mathbf b}}\ensuremath{^{(est)}}\ensuremath{_i}$`. Unfortunately, even defining the acronyms without the `{}` particle does not help. For this reason, I removed the green tick mark from this answer.